# Strongswan persistent connection

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, strongswan

I want to setup a persistent connection between a linux strongswan client and cisco router, which means ipsec tunnel will up forever?

Is it possible? In my current configuration, tunnel will down after it reach ikelifetime, then I need to manually bring it up.

Here is my strongswan configuration:

```
config setup
    uniqueids=never

conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev1
    type=tunnel
    left=%any
    auto=add
    dpdaction=clear
    margintime=0s
    rekeyfuzz=20%
conn cisco-ezvpn
    right=10.0.1.1
    left=10.0.1.2
    leftid=19
    leftsourceip=%config
    right=10.0.1.1
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    xauth_identity=test
    leftauth2=xauth
    xauth=client
    aggressive=yes
    leftauth=psk
    rightauth=psk
    ikelifetime=300s
    lifetime=300s
    ike=aes256-sha256-ecp256
    esp=aes256-sha256
```

Following is my IOS configuration(ipsec part):

```
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr aes 256
 hash sha256
 authentication pre-share
 group 19
 lifetime 300
!
crypto isakmp key test address 10.0.1.2       
crypto isakmp keepalive 10
!
crypto isakmp client configuration group RA
 key test
 domain test.com
 pool POOL
 acl split
 save-password
 netmask 255.255.255.0
!
crypto isakmp client configuration group 19
 key test123
 domain test.com
 pool POOL
 acl split
 save-password
 netmask 255.255.255.0
crypto isakmp profile test
   match identity group RA
   match identity group 19
   client authentication list AUTH
   isakmp authorization list NET
   client configuration address respond
   client configuration group 19
   virtual-template 1
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set test esp-aes 256 esp-sha256-hmac 
 mode tunnel
!
crypto ipsec profile ipsecprof
 set security-association lifetime kilobytes disable
 set transform-set test 
!         
!         
crypto map cmap 10 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 10.0.1.2
 set transform-set test 
 match address split
!
!
interface Virtual-Template1 type tunnel
 ip unnumbered Vlan10
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 tunnel source Vlan10
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel protection ipsec profile ipsecprof
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.248
 ip helper-address 10.0.1.1
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
```

Comment: Can you just remove the `lifetime` parameter?  Note that you have both `ikelifetime` and `lifetime` set to the same value, so it might be hard to know which is killing you.  I have something similar set up for a non-Cisco router and don't have this problem.  I'm sure you can make it work somehow.

Comment: I removed lifetime & ikelifetime, maximum IKE_SA was auto adjust to 10800s, but connection still break down after 5 minutes, because cisco rounter set the lifetime to 5 minutes.

Comment: So it seems like you addressed the issue on the StrongSwan side and now have an issue in your Cisco configuration. My experience was that I had to go back and forth several times between configuration on my router and configuration in StrongSwan in order to get the settings to be mutually compatible.  If you want to edit you question and show configuration from the Cisco, maybe someone can provide additional help.

Comment: I have added IOS part

Comment: @codefarmer did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue where my client's connection drops every 5 minutes (Ubuntu) while colleagues on Mac OS stay happily connected forever.

Comment: same question like @VincenzoPii. I have same problem

Comment: @inye I could solve that by using libreswan (I had to compile it from sources).